# How can you have an initial migration for migrating from a non-Realm persistence layer?

Tags: ios, realm

We are currently using NSUserDefaults for our data persistence and we want to start using Realm.  However, since there is no current Realm yet persisted upon first launch after adding Realm, no migrations will be run.  There is seemingly no way to migrate this "-1" schema to schema 0 using the Realm migration mechanism.

We'd like to do this:

```
// Given that there is no Realm file
// and the app has never run this code before
RLMMigrationBlock migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {
    if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
        // migrating NSUserDefaults to Realm
    }
};
[RLMRealm setDefaultRealmSchemaVersion:1 withMigrationBlock:migrationBlock];
[RLMRealm defaultRealm]; // this DOESN'T run the migration :(
```

We have thought of hacks to work around this, but were hoping that those won't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way around this would probably be to check if the default realm exists on disk, and if not, access it (which would create is), and then perform that `migration` manually.

Comment: Yea, that was our fallback idea as well.  Is there a reason Realm doesn't give you a way to do an initial migration for going from no-realm -> realm?  I would imagine this would be a common use case for people migrating from Core Data or NSUserDefaults.

Comment: We found that calling the migration block on creation was more confusing, as you weren't _really_ performing a migration then.